# minimizing MSE of estimator $\theta(a,b) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} Y_ia_i + b$

Tags: statistics, optimization, estimation

We have $Y_i = \theta + \epsilon$, $E\epsilon = 0$ and $Var(\epsilon) = 0.5$.

We have a proposed estimator for $\epsilon$ :

$\hat{\theta}(a,b) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} Y_ia_i + b$. And $a = (a_i)^n_{i=1}$ must satisfy the constraint $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} a_i = 1$

We want to find $a = (a_i)^n_{i=1}$ and $b$ minimize the MSE of our estimator. Here is some of my work:

MSE = $E[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2]$

My guess is we want to take the derivative with respect to $b$ and $a$ and find the optimal values that way. As in, minimize what is inside of the expectation.

I have 
$$ (\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2 = (\frac{1}{n} \sum Y_ia_i + b - \theta )^2\\ 
= (\frac{1}{n}\sum Y_i a_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum b - \theta)^2 \\
 = (\frac{1}{n}Y_i a_i + b - \theta)^2$$
We take the derivative with respect to b. 
$$2(\frac{1}{n}\sum Y_i a_i + b - \theta) $$
Setting that to zero we have $$b^* = \frac{n\theta}{2*\sum Y_ia_i}$$

Before I move on to follow the same steps with $a$ I am wondering whether this is the correct approach since I am having a hard time interpreting having an optimal value for variables in our estimator having $\theta$ in them.

Comment: Among other issues, you're forgetting the "mean" ("M") bit in "MSE."

Comment: Ah, I see that's why you take the expectation first in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakes in your simplification and you need to take the expectation $E[(\hat\theta-\theta)^2]$ before differentiating.
\begin{align*}
(\hat\theta-\theta)^2&=\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_ia_iY_i+b-\theta\Big)^2\\
&=\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_ia_i(Y_i-\theta)+b\Big)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\Big[\sum_ia_i(Y_i-\theta)\Big]^2+b^2+\frac{2}{n}\Big[\sum_ia_i(Y_i-\theta)\Big]b.
\end{align*}
Note
\begin{align*}
E\Big[\sum_ia_i(Y_i-\theta)\Big]&=\sum_ia_iE(Y_i-\theta)=0,\\
E\Big[\Big(\sum_ia_i(Y_i-\theta)\Big)^2\Big]&=\operatorname{Var}\Big[\sum_ia_i(Y_i-\theta)\Big]=\sum_ia_i^2\operatorname{Var}(Y_i-\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_ia_i^2.
\end{align*}
Then:
$$
E[(\hat\theta-\theta)^2]=\frac{1}{2n^2}\sum_ia_i^2+b^2.
$$
It remains to use Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
n\sum_ia_i^2=\sum_i1^2\sum_ia_i^2\geq\Big(\sum_i1\cdot a_i\Big)^2=n^2\implies\sum_ia_i^2\geq n
$$
and the observation $b^2\geq 0$ to find the optimal $a_i=1$ $\forall i$ and $b=0$.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how we go from the Cauchy-Schwartz  part. Do we now use our simplification to find the optimal $a$ and $b$?

Comment: never mind , Thank you!